# Importing from Text File Java question

Tags: java, text, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I decided to create a currency converter in Java, and have it so that it would pull the conversion values out of a text file (to allow for easy editability since these values are constantly changing). I did manage to do it by using the Scanner class and putting all the values into an ArrayList.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to add comments to the text file for the user to read, which Scanner will ignore. "//" doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best way would be to read the file line by line using [`java.io.BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and scan every line for comments using [`String#startsWith()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) where in you searches for `"//"`.

But have you considered using a properties file and manage it using the [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API? This way you can benefit from a ready-made specification and API's and you can use # as start of comment line. Also see the [tutorial at sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Comment: use a properties file, it will greatly simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner wont ignore anything, you will have to remove the comments from your data after you have read it in.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) is possibly the easiest, then perform your necessary tests. currentLine.split(regex) is also very handy for converting a line into an array of values using a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

With Java nio, you could do something like this. Assuming you want to ignore lines that start with "//" and end up with an ArrayList.

```java
List<String> dataList;
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", "data.txt");
dataList = Files.lines(path)
             .filter(line -> !(line.startsWith("//")))
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```